# Share Wired Ethernet Internet Connection via Wifi Adapter to Connect from Android

Tags: networking, internet, kde, android, ethernet

I am using ubuntu 14.04 with kde plasma and i want to share my wired ethernet internet connection via my realtek **RTL8188eu** Wifi adapter so i can connect and browse internet from my android Samsung Galaxy Grand i9082 that is running cyanogenmod 11

```
shady@shady:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:0061 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

i have tried some tutorials involving hostapd but that dont work maybe because i am using kde

Answer (score 2):

According to ubuntu documentation, it is pretty easy.

1.Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select System Settings.

2.Open Network and select Wireless on the left.

3.Click the Use as Hotspot button.

4. If you are already connected to a wireless network, you will be asked if you want to disconnect from that network. A single wireless adapter can only connect to or create one network at a time. Click Create Hotspot to confirm.

https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html